# Can someone explain the Query Caching for JPA or post some good links

Tags: jpa, openjpa

```
 Query "{myquery}" is removed from cache  excluded permanently. 
 Query "{myquery}" is not cached because its result is not obtained by executing a 
 select statement. This can happen if the query was evaluated in-memory. The result
 was provided by org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryCacheStoreQuery$CachingResultObjectProvider.
```

I am getting this openjpa warning message in my logs constantly. We have set L2 caching for both query and data. It seems to me that in essence it means that the data is being fetched from the QueryCache results. But I would not have expected a warning just by setting L2 caching

Comment: "QueryCache" is not part of JPA. It is specific to your JPA provider. L2 caching is something different, unrelated to queries as such

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. But would you be able hint at what is this openjpa specific message trying to communicate. Also some links to in-memory query evaluations and query caching concepts would be really good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about the [Prepared SQL Cache](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual.html#ref_guide_cache_querysql) in the user manual.